# How can export user with pwdchangedtime in openldap server to another openldap server

Tags: openldap

I am using openldap 2.4.42 version with policyd. I installed new version openldap server and I want export all user to new openldap.  It's export is succussfull but without user password "pwdChangedTime". How can export user with pwdChangedTime in openldap server to another openldap server?

Comment: It's an operational attribute and so won't get copied. You could have done the export via replication and then turned it off. Or if the new server is to replace the old just copy the whole DIT.

Comment: The new server will replace the old one. How can I copy the entire DIT?